# synchronization of multiple Android apps

Tags: android, synchronization

How to create an app A, that opens a mobile game app B (e.g. doodle jump, etc.) and after the player looses the game app A closes app B and imports the score from app B in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android runs each application in isolated sandbox so by default you don't have privilege to access other apps data. But there is one exception to that and that is if Both app is yours. If you also developed app B then yes you can make app A access app B if both app use the same app user id. That means both apps run under the same sandbox and can access any data from each other. 
If that's your case watch this youtube video. It will fully explain how to do it. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4u-xpB1RFfs&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hmkEaYIvLLm5IEGM0kpwU

**Updated Answer** 

The simpler way to achieve this to simply post a broadcast by your first application and get it from the second one! Just note that any other app can listen for your broadcast as well and you should consider security issues.

Comment: hello @Cœur I posted this answer about 4 years ago, I don't have any documentation in my mind right now. you have to search for it

Comment: @Reza I'm not an Android dev: my comment was just an advice for the quality of your answer. Thank you for updating it.